# How to run tests in parallel in Django?

Tags: django, testing, parallel-processing

In my Django projects I use sqlite database to run tests. Since it uses only memory, it's much faster than MySQL, but it's still not fast enough. During tests, only one of 4 processors is used, and not much memory is consumed. So, I'd like to have 4 sqlite databases in memory to run 4 tests in parallel.

Has anyone tried this?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily recommend using sqlite for testing if you aren't using it in production. It's generally not recommended and I've found that often tests may pass in sqllite but not in postgres for example.

Comment: True, but since sqlite runs much faster, it is very useful to use it during development, and then run tests on same database as production only prior to make a PR.

Comment: I agree with @Aaron to not change the DB to SQLite if you're using PostgreSQL in production because it'll reduce the test accuracy.

Comment: In our current project, we have almost 700 tests. I have no idea how long they take to run on my computer, because it's run by github actions. I've split tests in 5 different actions, each one covering part of the tests, and they can take 10 minutes to run. Last week I changed the precision of a DecimalField in db and broken tests were sparsely distributed around the application. I don't use sqlite for tests, and I think it would have saved me a few hours locating broken tests. 12 years later, this problem is still very relevant, and unsolved.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since Django 1.9 it's possible to run the tests in parallel by Django with its built-in unit-test features.

Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-parallel

Comment: Worth noting that this runs test *classes* in parallel but not the methods. From the docs: "Django distributes test cases — unittest.TestCase subclasses — to subprocesses."

Answer (score 9):

According to the Django 3.0 [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests-in-parallel) there is a `--parallel` option that you can use.

> --parallel [N]
>   Runs tests in separate parallel processes. Since modern processors have multiple cores, this allows running tests significantly faster.

So you can use the following command to execute the tests in parallel.

```
python manage.py test --parallel
```

> You can adjust the number of processes either by providing it as the option’s value, e.g. --parallel=4, or by setting the DJANGO_TEST_PROCESSES environment variable.

This can help considerably reduce your test execution time if you have a large Django project with quite a few test unit cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a parallel test runner for Django and Twisted described here: http://www.tomaz.me/2011/04/03/making-django-and-twisted-tests-faster.html (the source lives here https://github.com/Kami/parallel-django-and-twisted-test-runner - link at the end of the post). You can use it as described in Django docs on testing.

There is also a nose parallel test runner.

Answer (score -8):

You can easily split the testing for apps on parrallalel on linux by:

```
$ python manage.py test cms & \
python manage.py test blog & \
python manage.py test store & \
python manage.py test registration
$
```

Could be helpfull for big projects with a lot of apps, the best would be a bash scripts that runs tests every four apps.

Comment: Doesn't work. Tests in background behave strangely, some of them stop to work. Besides, even if they do work, output is scrambled (not a big problem). Finally, most applications finish fast while only two processors end up processing two heavy applications...

Comment: I am strange that tests in background behave strangely, do you have more data about that issue? I see that what you want in some way is to distribute the load test by test ... interesting, unfortunately I don't have a clear idea how to solve your need. Keep this question update if you find something interesting to do.

Comment: You could try using Python's processing libs to run the tests in parallel and capture the output. In addition you'll probably want to use a separate sqlite db for each (define this by --settings) to avoid monkey business described above.